# MySQL add timestamp when saving data

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp, database-table

I have this php script to save data to a database hourly, and I was wondering how to add a timestamp when the data is saved.  (also, what should I put as Length/Values in phpMyAdmin)  The columns in my table are:

Number, Name, Type, Null, Default

1,  Timestamp,  timestamp,          No,     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

2,  BTC,    float,          Yes,    NULL

3,  USD,    float,          Yes,    NULL

My script:

```
<?php
$json_url = "https://crypto-trade.com/api/1/ticker/dvc_btc";
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);
$DVCdata = $json_feed->data;
$DVCask = $DVCdata->min_ask;
$json_url1 = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD";
$json_data1 = file_get_contents($json_url1);
$json_feed1 = json_decode($json_data1);
$BTCask = $json_feed1->ask;
$DVC_USD = $BTCask * $DVCask;
$DVCround = round($DVC_USD, 8);
$connection = mysqli_connect("mysql.serversfree.com",user,pass,database); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO database (Timestamp, BTC, USD)
VALUES (???, '$DVCask', '$DVCround')");

mysqli_close($connection);    
?>
```

Comment: time() is a PHP function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your column defaults to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP just take out that field entirely - it will get the default value

```
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO database (BTC, USD) VALUES ('$DVCask', '$DVCround')");
```

Bear in mind it will be the time on the database rather than the webserver if those are different machines and the time is not in sync.

Comment: Also, be sure to set the column to update the timestamp on record update or else it will only be set when the record is INSERTED. More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Is there anything I need to put into length/values in phpmyadmin or should I just leave it blank?

Comment: Should be OK as it is - I don't know phpadmin but there are no length parameters for a timestamp and it is already defaulted to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in your question.

Comment: I took out the field and I opened the script.  Is there a way to verify that it was successful?  I opened up the table and nothing showed up.  It says this: "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0002 sec )"

Comment: It looks like the INSERT query didn't run if you have no rows in the database - how did you run it?

Answer (score 0):

try NOW()

```
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO database (Timestamp, BTC, USD)
VALUES (NOW(), '$DVCask', '$DVCround')");
```

The value will be formatted as such : 2013-10-12 11:18:02. depending on your field type, only the date or the date and the time will be saved. To save only the date, the field type should be DATE, if you want to keep the hour as well, use DATETIME

for the other fields, as they seem to contain dollar values you might want to use decimal fields instead? keep in mind that in the length attribute of the field, you have to enter two numbers, the first being the total number of digits, the second the number of digits after the comma, like 5,2

Comment: What should I add in length/values for the timestamp and the other columns?  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Timestamp field as **datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()**. That will get the current date/time for you.

More details here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp

If you want to use the php synthax you could define a variable $**timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');** and after that use:

```
<?php
$json_url = "https://crypto-trade.com/api/1/ticker/dvc_btc";
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);
$DVCdata = $json_feed->data;
$DVCask = $DVCdata->min_ask;
$json_url1 = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD";
$json_data1 = file_get_contents($json_url1);
$json_feed1 = json_decode($json_data1);
$BTCask = $json_feed1->ask;
$DVC_USD = $BTCask * $DVCask;
$DVCround = round($DVC_USD, 8);
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$connection = mysqli_connect("mysql.serversfree.com",user,pass,database); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO database (Timestamp, BTC, USD)
VALUES ('$timestamp', '$DVCask', '$DVCround')");

mysqli_close($connection);    
?>
```

Cheers

Comment: Where should I set it?  In phpmyadmin or in the script itself?

Comment: @Smeagol I updated the whole script for you. Copy and paste it, and it should work. I added a **$timestamp variable** with the **php value: date('Y-m-d H:i:s');**

That will work, and set the current date/time for you and store it in the database. You only need to **change the "Timestamp" field** in phpmyadmin **to datetime**

Comment: it's giving me an invalid default value error (#1067)  What should I do?

Comment: @Smeagol what is giving you the error? The copy / paste script? Did you change the field type in your database?

Comment: I changed the timestamp field to datetime in phpmyadmin

Comment: I might be mistaking here, but try to set the field type back to **timestamp** and try again

Comment: I changed it back, I can run the script now but nothing is inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your column datatype as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, then there is no need of adding value in query.

If you have not used then,

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```